# Trying to understand power function, C Programming Language, 2e, 27

Tags: c

I'm working my way through The C Programming Language, K&R, 2nd edition, page 26, about the power() function, and I'm confused by something:

```
int power(int base, int n)
{
    int p;

    for (p = 1; n > 0; --n)
        p = p * base;
    return p;
}
```

How does p get incremented? If the for loop "runs backwards until it becomes zero", why is it n > 0 and not n = 0?

Comment: Why don't you try to run it with =0 and see what you get?

Comment: `p` isn't getting incremented, it's getting multiplied by `base` at every iteration of the loop. The loop stops when `n` has reached zero.

Comment: By multiplying `p = p * base;`

Comment: Run code like this with pencil and paper to better understand how it works....

Comment: The loop condition is `n > 0` because it is a condition for another iteration to be performed, not a condition for the loop to exit.

Comment: Picturing it with a `while` loop may help, try with a simple output producing analog e.g. `int p = 1, n = 10, base = 5; while (n--) printf ("%d\n", (p = p * base));`

Answer (score 2):

`p` is incremented by the following line:

```
p = p * base;
```

You might read this as "take value `p`, multiply it by `base`, and store it into `p`".

> If the for loop "runs backwards until it becomes zero", why is it n > 0 and not n = 0?

The second argument in the for-loop is used to determine *if the loop should run*. Therefore `n > 0` means "As long as `n` is greater than `0`, run the loop", while `n == 0` would mean "As long as `n` is equal to `0`, run the loop".

The intended purpose here is to run the loop `n` times. You subtract `1` from `n` each time, and then stop the loop once it becomes `0`. This will have multiplied `p` by `base` for `n` times.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `p` is never incremented. It is multiplied by a factor of `base` each time the loop runs.  The return value contains the desired power.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (p = 1; n > 0; --n)
```

I don't like this full of tricks style of programming as it makes code more difficult to understand for humans. In such a trivial example it is not the big issue, but in the large & complex code making it even more complex and heavy to read is a horrible programming manner

```
int power(int base, int n)
{
    int p = 1;
    int x;

    for (x = 0; x < n; x++)
        p = p * base;
    return p;
}
```

Isn't it easier to read? If you are worried about the additional x variable - do not. It will be optimized out by the compiler. In the K&R era such micro optimisations were necessary buy nowadays, thanks God, we can focus on effective algorithms, leaving the micro optimisations to the compilers - and as practice shows they are much better than 99.99% of the coders

Comment: I am not sure that I would call this code "full of tricks," but more to the point, this does not answer the question: "How does p get incremented? If the for loop runs backwards until it becomes zero, why is it n > 0 and not n = 0?"

Comment: To be fair, David, it was the whole thing I was having trouble understanding, even if I did not explicitly say so.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the great replies. I didn't respond straight away but I did notice how quickly I got several replies. If I only I'd tried this site years ago :-)